# Почему получаю ошибку в input, SetStateAction is not assignable string?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

у меня есть инпут в который юзер должен ввести некое число и потом я это число присваиваю в стейт но получаю ошибку от тс "Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction'"

Есть такой код:

```js
const [num, setNum] = React.useState<number>(0);

<input
     placeholder="Enter your number"
     value={num}
     onChange={handleNum}
 />
```

Далее пишу функцию и уже в ней получаю ошибку:

```js
const handleNum: React.ChangeEventHandler<HTMLInputElement> = (
    e
  ) => {
    setNum(e.target.value);/*Returns the value of the data at the cursor's current position.

Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<number>'*/
  };
```

Почему у меня тип получается строка если я явно указал 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Потому что из элемента input приходит строка и данные надо в явном виде преобразовать в число. `Number()` или `parseInt()` решайте сами в зависимости от задачи )

```
const handleNum: React.ChangeEventHandler<HTMLInputElement> = (
    e
  ) => {
    setNum(Number(e.target.value));/*Returns the value of the data at the cursor's current position.

Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<number>'*/
  };
```

А лучше выполнить проверки того, что пользователь там ввел

Comment: Спасибо, да, так и сделаю